# Store boolean expression into a variable

Tags: pattern-matching, variable-definitions, variable, boolean-computation

My purpose is to use a boolean expression as a requirement that a pattern must comply. The requirement is `c1 == "a"`, and I am using it to select a string from a list:

```
Select[{"abc","def"},StringMatchQ[#, 
   StartOfString ~~ c1_~~__~~EndOfString /; 
    c1 == "a"] &]
```

However I want to specify that condition to be satisfied through a variable `var` that I can assign the expression that I may need:

```
Select[{"abc","def"},StringMatchQ[#, 
       StartOfString ~~ c1_~~__~~EndOfString /; 
        var] &]
```

However doing `var = c1==a` does not do the job. Is there a way to just store that expression, maybe in some other type of variable? My ultimate aim is to create a list of such variables, with several conditions in each entry to be satisfied when a determined entry be selected at different steps within a `do` loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a pure function to store the boolean expression:

```
var = # == "a" &;
```

You can use it with [`PatternTest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html)

```
Select[{"abc", "def"}, 
 StringMatchQ[StartOfString ~~ c1_?var ~~ __ ~~ EndOfString]]
```

> {"abc"}

or with [`Condition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html):

```
Select[{"abc", "def"}, 
 StringMatchQ[StartOfString ~~ c1_ ~~ __ ~~ EndOfString /; var[c1]]]
```

> {"abc"}

Comment: Is this solution also suitable for lists? For example, `list = {#1=="a", #2=="b"}&` to then use it with its corresponding arguments,`list[c1,c2]?` Or would it be necessary to make individual pure functions `list = {#=="a"&, #=="b"&}`, what would make it much more inconvenient to specify its arguments in `PatternTest` or `Condition`? This latter case wouldn't allow me to use it in my intended purpose

Comment: @abcd, with `list = {#1=="a", #2=="b"}&` the function call `list[c1,c2]` with return a list (`{True, True}`, `{False, True}` ...  etc) . The predicate in Condition or PatternTest to evaluate to `True` or `False`. So,  if you define `list`  as, for example, ` list =And[#1=="a", #2=="b"]&` or as `list = Or[#1=="a", #2=="b"]&` it should work.